# How to add menu in OpenCart 1.5.6.1 - accordion menu

Tags: opencart

I have installed OpenCart version 1.5.6.1. I want to add menu! How to add menu in OpenCart?

Comment: Admin or frontend? If frontend -  product, category or information page? Please explain your requirement clearly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, make sure to go through OpenCart documentation (can be found at http://www.opencart.com) and walk through sections for administrators first. After You have learned how to work with OpenCart as an administrator and will have the desire for developing for OpenCart then You can read also the docs for developers. Afterwards if You still will have some problems or questions understanding something, go to ask to OpenCart forums first. **But if You would have some programming problems, feel free to come back here and ask Your question.**

Answer (score 0):

1. Login into admin
2. Go to `Catalog > Categories`, click the `edit` button of the category you need to add in menu.
3. Select `Data` tab.
4. Click on checkbox option for "`Top:
   Display in the top menu bar. Only works for the top parent categories.`"
5. Save.

That's it.

Have a nice day !!